# Looking for XSL templates using Google Charts API?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, google, html-popup, xsl

I am searching for examples on usage of ArcGIS Desktop HTML popups in general, being more specific on xsl templates using google charts api on it.

Are there any references available?

Answer (score 1):

Here is reference to xsl with GC (google charts) which might be helpful.
[csharp blog](http://csharptechies.blogspot.com/2011/06/google-charts-in-xsl.html)
And another showing "cool tool" for GC.
[cool tool](http://services.renderx.com/lists/xep-support/6006.html)
here is a Wiki just scan down to google charts.
[Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery)
And ESRI webhelp shows using an xsl (scroll down).
[esri webhelp](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_HTML_pop_up_properties_for_feature_layers/00s50000002r000000/)