# Can ArcMap do HTML pop up with a chart?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcgis-desktop, html, chart

am using Arcmap 10.0 to create a map. Need to display a chart for my data when users click on the marker. Must I use plugin like google chart? Can I do it directly in Arcmap?

Comment: Some overlap with [**another question**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17292/looking-for-xsl-templates-using-google-charts-api) that would be good to resolve along with this one.  It's not a duplicate.

Comment: Will the chart be generated on the fly?  Or are you referencing an existing graphic like a jpeg image or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can create pie, bar or stacked charts in ArcMap

for the html pop - you might have to write some code:

The end result is:

[image]

> Right-click the layer you want to draw showing quantitative values
>   using pie charts and click Properties. Click the Symbology tab on the
>   Layer Properties dialog box. Click Charts and click Pie.

[image]

End Result is:

[image]

Sources:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000016000000

HTML Popup with chart

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002r000000